# Multiple consumers using spring kafka with reply topic being written outside spring

Tags: spring-kafka

I am using Spring-Kafka and trying to achieve request reply pattern. My use case is, client calls Rest endpoint with payload, I am sending this message to a kafka topic(request topic). I have spark job which consumes this message, processes it and sends response in another kafka topic(reply-topic). Once the message is written back to reply topic, my web application should consume this message and return as http response to the client.

**What I have achieved so far.**

I am using Spring-Kafka for solving this use case. I am able to send a request body as kafka message to request topic. Spring-Kafka is generating a kafka_correlationId as kafka header before sending the kafka message. I have registered the producerInterceptor, got hold of correlationId generated and passing this in the message body.

In spark job, I am able to consume this kafka message, process it and while sending back in reply-topic, I am adding message header kafka_correlationId with same value as what is generated.

When I have single consumer, use case is working perfectly fine.

**What is not working.**

Now, I have deployed 2 instances of my web application, reply-topic has 2 partitions with same consumer group Id.

```
App-instance-1 : consuming from partition-0
App-instance-2 : consuming from partition-1
```

If my request goes to App-instance-1 and If my spark job is able to write to partion-0 of reply-topic, I am able to get the response. However, If spark job writes to partion-1 in reply-topic, since App-instance-1 is listening for only partion-0, I am not able to get the response and app fails with timeout exception. Similar case for another app instance.

Please let me know what I am supposed to configure to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions -

- also set the REPLY_PARTITION header (and have the spark app send the reply to that partition) - and statically assign the partitions.
- use a different `group.id` in each instance so that both clients get the reply - in this case, set `sharedReplyTopic` to avoid log noise when an instance gets a reply for a request he didn't send.

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.6.2/reference/html/#replying-template).

> When you configure with a single reply `TopicPartitionOffset`, you can use the same reply topic for multiple templates, as long as each instance listens on a different partition. When configuring with a single reply topic, each instance must use a different `group.id`. In this case, all instances receive each reply, but only the instance that sent the request finds the correlation ID. This may be useful for auto-scaling, but with the overhead of additional network traffic and the small cost of discarding each unwanted reply. When you use this setting, we recommend that you set the template’s `sharedReplyTopic` to `true`, which reduces the logging level of unexpected replies to DEBUG instead of the default ERROR.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question so that it can help others.

As per @Gary Russel input, I went ahead with setting REPLY_PARTITION  header in the message.

Instead of assigning partitions statically to the consumers(since I am not sure how many consumers I am going to have in my application), I chose to identify the assigned partitions dynamically and passing it along in the REPLY_PARTITION header. Below is the code to achieve the same.

Define the bean which listens for reply-topic.

```
@Bean
public KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, JsonNode> replyContainer(ConsumerFactory<String, JsonNode> cf) {
    ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties("reply-topic");
    return new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(cf, containerProperties);
}
```

To get assigned partition,

```
@Autowired
private KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, JsonNode> replyContainer;

    /**
     * <P>
     *     gets first assigned partition
     * </P>
     * @return
     */
    private Integer getAssignedPartition() throws Exception {
        Integer partitionId = null;
        if (replyContainer.getAssignedPartitions() != null) {
            for (TopicPartition assignedPartition : replyContainer.getAssignedPartitions()) {
                if(assignedPartition.topic().equalsIgnoreCase("reply-topic")){
                    partitionId = assignedPartition.partition();
                }
            }
        }
        if(partitionId == null){
            //throw exception
        }
        return partitionId;
    }

    /**
     * <P>
     *     int to byte array
     * </P>
     * @param value
     * @return
     */
    private static byte[] toByteArray(int value) {
        return new byte[] {
                (byte) (value >> 24), (byte) (value >> 16), (byte) (value >> 8), (byte) value
        };
    }
```

Method which sends and waits for reply-topic.

```
/**
 * <P>
 *     Sends message to request topic and wait for reply-topic response.
 * </P>
 * @param request
 * @return
 * @throws Exception
 */
public JsonNode process(JsonNode request) throws Exception {
    // create producer record
    Integer partitionId = getAssignedPartition();
    ProducerRecord<String, JsonNode> record = new ProducerRecord<>(requestTopic, request);
    // set reply topic in header
    record.headers().add(new RecordHeader(KafkaHeaders.REPLY_TOPIC, requestReplyTopic.getBytes()));
    record.headers().add(new RecordHeader(KafkaHeaders.REPLY_PARTITION, toByteArray(partitionId) ));
    RequestReplyFuture<String, JsonNode, JsonNode> sendAndReceive = kafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive(record);
    
    // get consumer record
    ConsumerRecord<String, JsonNode> consumerRecord = sendAndReceive.get(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    // return consumer value
    return consumerRecord.value();
}
```